# php mysql array data insert if not exists else update

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert or update array data into mysql database.

my array look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [R_ID] => 32
            [email] => a@a.com
            [name] => Bob
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [R_ID] => 32
            [email] => b@b.com
            [name] => Dan
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [R_ID] => 32
            [email] => c@c.com
            [name] => Paul
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [R_ID] => 35
            [email] => d@d.com
            [name] => Mike
        )  
)
```

I am using this code to insert data into mysql database.

```
if(is_array($EMailArr)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO email_list (R_ID, EMAIL, NAME) values ";

    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($EMailArr as $row){

        $R_ID = (int) $row['R_ID'];
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['email'] );
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['name'] );

        $valuesArr[] = "('$R_ID', '$email', '$name')";
    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}
```

But I want if array R_ID value match with any row R_ID value then query update existing value otherwise query insert a new row.

I cant understand how can i do that.

Comment: I'd start by not using mysql_* functions, they're deprecated. Rewrite using PDO, it's a way better db abstraction layer. To answer your question, I guess I'd run a query on the db to see if the record exists, if it does update it, if it doesn't insert it. http://php.net/pdo

Comment: I'm gonna depress... Do I always have to ask: `What is the problem? What have you tried so far?` on every question?

Comment: Use MySQL INSERT....ON DUPLICATE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **INSERT** with **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** to update table records when key already exists.

Refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for details and syntax